# Which is "Visa Country of Issue" as asked by Air India?

Tags: visas, india, german-citizens, air-india

I am trying to check in online for my flight on Air India. It asks for the "Visa country of issue".

Do they mean where I applied for the visa? I am German and did it in Germany.

Does it mean India, the country to which I'm travelling and which issued my visa?

Comment: Generally it means the country that issued the visa (not the location of the country's consulate).  But without firsthand knowledge of the context, I can't be certain that this is the correct answer in this case.

Comment: Yes it should be India. I have checked in a few times on AI website and I am confident about it. Visa country of issue of your final destination.

Comment: Also Indian visa itself does not mention in which country it was issued (only in MRI)

Comment: @anshabhi perhaps you can post an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be INDIA.

In general scenarios, only the Government (or Govt officials representing that country) can issue visa for that country.

Air India flies to many countries, and they fly many global citizens worldwide.
In above scenario, you are traveling to India, and got your visa issued by Indian Embassy in Germany. Since Indian Embassy represents Indian Government, it should be INDIA as "Visa Country of Issue".

Comment: This worked out fine.

Comment: also they have this question "Country where the visa applies" this also will be India. Basically both will be the foreign country which you are travelling.

Answer (score 2):

Several comments have mentioned that the likely answer is **India** and that's what I would put in there. In the worst case scenario Air India will correct the information when you get to the airport, whatever information you put in during check-in is not crucial.

Answer (score -3):

They are referring to Germany since the Visa was issued by the Indian embassy/consulate in Germany.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this assertion?

Comment: @phoog Unfortunately it doesn't state it on the Indian visa page in my passport, otherwise I'd share a pic. However this is what I entered when applying for my visa initially and again when transferring it to a new passport.

Comment: But the question isn't about a visa application; it's about checking in for a flight. I would expect the answer to be different in different contexts.

Comment: @phoog the question is about the visa country of issue. How can it be different in different contexts? This person applied for the Indian visa in Germany. Hence Germany is the country of issue.

Comment: The visa was issued by India, in Germany.  "Country of issue" is inherently ambiguous; it could be asking "in what country" or "by which country."  Obviously, in the context of the Indian bureaucracy, they are interested in *where* the visa was issued.  In the context of any other bureaucracy, especially that of an airline, they are more likely to want to know *which country* issued the visa under its laws, for the purpose of travel to its territory.

Comment: @phoog it's an indian visa, that doesn't change. Where it was issued does.

Comment: Right, but when you check in for a flight to India, they want to know that you have a visa issued by India.  They don't care which consulate issued it, or whether that consulate was in Germany or any other country.  In other words, by asking the country of issue, they want to confirm that it is Indian visa.

Comment: I think I finally see your point. It is a strange phrasing, right? Would have been much simpler to ask "do you have an Indian visa? Y/N" but then again it's India and they do things very strangely.